# CSV Parser for 'Importing large CSV files via Batch Apex '

Tags: apex, csv

I need help for **Importing large CSV files via Batch Apex**. I have tried this link =>
http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/ .But unable to implement it.Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're encountering? The implementation is not trivial, and there could be many stumbling blocks along the way. Please use [gists](http://gist.github.com) or something to share you code as well, since that would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to reference a static variable incorrectly.

Change

```
return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile, m_parser.crlf);
```

to

```
return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile, Parser.crlf);
```

When you want to reference a static member you prefix it with the class name and do not use an instance of the class.

Comment: I have corrected it. Now that error is not coming. But still unable to implement the logic. need help. Does anyone have code of a working model where 'Importing CSV files by batch apex' is implemented.

Comment: If you're having problems with the logic I would suggest a new question to cover the specifics.

Answer (score 5):

Try this [**ImportCSVJob** class](https://gist.github.com/martyychang/e133652e35bc6bd89ac3) as a reference implementation of `Database.Batchable` and `Schedulable`. The class demonstrates how you can use [CSVReader](http://frombelvideres4thfloor.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ietf-rfc-4180-compliant-csv-reader-for.html) to read CSV data, construct new records and then insert those records.

Try testing your job with the [simple **Lead-import.csv** data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByKgdEYM0TXxWGdZY1NuR1FFNnc/view?usp=sharing) below:

```
FirstName,LastName,Company
Marty,Chang,Slalom Consulting
Homer,Simpson,Springfield Nuclear Power Plant
```

You can schedule the job or run the job using the Developer Console to execute the following as anonymous Apex:

```
Database.executeBatch(new ImportCSVJob(), 1);
```